# Maven multi-module project upload to Nexus approach with overriding distribution

Tags: java, maven, deployment, nexus, maven-deploy-plugin

I have multimodule maven project

```
project
 -submodule1
  - pom.xml
 -submodule2
  - pom.xml
...
 -submoduleN
  - pom.xml
 -pom.xml
```

The parent pom contains `<distributionManagement>` section which is actual for most of the submodels. Each submodule inherits parent pom. But I have 2 sumbodules where I would like to override distributionManagement section. I can achieve it with

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <altDeploymentRepository>cn-archetypes::default::https://repository.company.com/content/repositories/archetypes/</altDeploymentRepository>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

Everything is ok except the fact that I would like to disable deployment of snapshots. I could achieve it `nexus-staging-maven-plugin` with `skipStaging`=true.

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <altDeploymentRepository>cn-archetypes::default::https://repository.company.com/content/repositories/archetypes/</altDeploymentRepository>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.8</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                    <configuration>
                        <skipStaging>true</skipStaging>
                        <serverId>cn-archetypes</serverId>
                        <nexusUrl>https://repository.company.com/</nexusUrl>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

But when I do that I got "Return code is: 400, ReasonPhrase: Bad Request."

I tried different combinations of maven-deployment-plugin and nexus plugin but there is no luck. Could someone suggest correct combination of properties for these deploy plugins or other approach to achieve overriding parent distribution management section with disabling staging deployment in a child submodule?

Comment: First important question: `But I have 2 sumbodules where I would like to override distributionManagement section. ` Why?

Comment: @khmarbaise N sub-modules refer to private repos and 2 extra to public. Semantically  this sub-modules have lots of in common but have to be published to different repos.

Comment: I would extract those two modules into a separate build and consume the other artifacts as dependencies. That will solve the issue and makes your build easier and you can do that via CI solution without any issue...That means that everyone who likes to consume them you have to have access to both ...

Comment: @khmarbaise What do you mean when saying "separate build"? (moving to separate maven project, or don't inherit the parent)

Comment: Separate maven project...